# Windows phone and Sqlite. Making a select

Tags: c#, sqlite, select, windows-phone

```
/*
List<BD.Usuario> items = null;
items = App.db.Query<BD.Usuario>("select Nome from Usuario");
lista.ItemsSource = items;
*/

string Email;
Email = App.db.Query<BD.Usuario>("select Email from Usuario").ToString();

MessageBox.Show(Email);
```

What's in the comment works to connect to a `listbox`.
Now I want to select a single record from the database to a variable!

The example code does not work. How would I do this select?

Look image in my Onedrive:
http://1drv.ms/1lIL44L

Open link. please.

```
var returnedCollection = App.db.Query<BD.Usuario>("select Email from Usuario");
        for (int i = 0; i < returnedCollection.Count(); i++)
        {
            string email = (returnedCollection[i]).ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(email);
        }

        return;
```

Would the button code (the code above). I have the value in the variable, but does not show the value in `messagebox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked:

```
var returnedCollection = App.db.Query(“select Email from Usuario”);
for (int i = 0; i < returnedCollection.Count(); i++)
{
MessageBox.Show(returnedCollection[0].Email.ToString());
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

the Query method returns an `IEnumerable<T>` (in your case `IEnumerable<BD.Usuario>`), which can't be casted correctly to string unless you've overridden the base `ToString()` method. Consider that there could be several items in the return value of the query and not just one.

If you want to access all the elements present in the returned collection you should iterate on them:

```
var returnedCollection=App.db.Query<BD.Usuario>("select Email from Usuario");
foreach(var item in returnedCollection){
    string email=item.ToString();
    //Do Stuffs...
    }
```

Since it seems OP doesn't know the foreach construct, here's a version with a for...

```
var returnedCollection=App.db.Query<BD.Usuario>("select Email from Usuario");
    for(int i=0; i < returnedCollection.Count(); i++){
        string email=(returnedCollection[i]).ToString();
        //Do Stuffs...
        }
```

Comment: "unless you've overridden the base ToString() method." did not, how would I do to get the value then?

Comment: The simplest way would be to Iterate on the elements present in the Collection returned by the Query Method.

Comment: I did not! How would this in practice? How would the code? Or pass me a link explaining.

Comment: You can iterate on a collection with either a for statement or a foreach statement, as example.

Comment: the foreach statement ever used. I'll open another program here. But you do not have an example there for me no? More or less similar to the case al. May have if a Where SQL example: "select email from usuario where code = 1"

Comment: I am not exactly sure of what I should see, but I'd advise you to keep each topic for a single question, in order to make the answers and moderation (editing, upvoting, etc.) process easier. So if you have another doubt, you should open another question.

Comment: But it's the same issue. :) 
The code did not work. The picture you can see. In listbox showed the records already in the code does not show the record register. Just shows what the messagebox.

Comment: Your image is not clear, can you formulate what exactly is the issue with the code?